# jQuery - smooth scale transformation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scale, css-transforms

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17g0g2f5/1/).

So now on scroll it uses 2 transform functions. A translation function that creates a parallax effect and a scale function that adds a nice touch to the effect. But as you can see the scaling goes way too fast:

```
currentElement.css({
    "transform": "translateY(" + translation + "px) scale(1." + scrolled + ")"
 });
```

So what I want is to have the scale effect be smooth and increase slowly, but noticeably.

I think `scale` should not be more than `1.09` when the element is no longer in view and it should return to `1.0` when `scrolled = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding transition and see if it works, like:

```
-webkit-transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
```

it looks fine to me.

Comment: No, that's not what I want, I don't want to delay the effect, I want to *increase/decrease the scale slowly* while scrolling. I updated the JSFiddle with a possible solution, but it's still too fast.